# Difference between twarn and tassert in Talend

Tags: etl, talend

Please let me know the difference between the two components **twarn** and **tassert** in Talend?

Really I don't found the utility of the creation of these components separatley? What is the need/utility of each one on real use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**twarn** : This component provides a priority-rated message to the next component. It does not stop your Job in case of error. If you want to kill a Job in case of error, see tDie. (taken from Talend Help center docs)

**tassert** : This evaluate the status of a Job execution. It concludes with the boolean result based on an assertive statement related to the execution and feed the result to tAssertCatcher for proper Job status presentation.(taken from Talend Help center docs)

For use-case, please follow the below link:

[Error Handling in Talend](https://help.talend.com/reader/E1BqTO4L4tsoYZpJhZn_OA/5M~MAYpe~1DoN0oQaUmNiA)